# Google sheets importxml formula error

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-sheets

I try to import some Google Maps data into Google Sheets using the importxml function.

My URL looks like this:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=Disneyland&destination=Universal+Studios+Hollywood4&sensor=false&alternatives=false&key=MYGOOGLEAPIKEY
(replace MYGOOGLEAPIKEY with yours or remove the whole key parameter)

In a browser this returns the XML as expected.

However if I use

=IMPORTXML("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=Disneyland&destination=Universal+Studios+Hollywood4&sensor=false&alternatives=false&key=MYGOOGLEAPIKEY","//leg/distance/value");

in Google Spreadsheets I get a error message pop-up stating:

> There was a problem
>
> It looks like your formula has an error. If you don't want to enter a
>   formula, begin your text with an apostrophe (').

[Screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbQlz.png)

I am unable to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Remove `;` at the end? Does other formula like VLOOKUP work?

Comment: Ok. Feeling kind of stupid now. The ; at the end was indeed the culprit. Thx a lot!

Comment: Ups! Same for me! Thanks for the not @TheMaster!